# Eukaryotic equivalent of bacterial tmRNA

Tags: rna, translation, ribosome, noncoding-rna

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RNAs?wprov=sfti1) Wikipedia article,
tmRNA is only found in bacteria, with its purpose being to “rescue stalled ribosomes”.

This brings me to the question of is there a eukaryotic equivalent of this RNA? If not, how do eukaryotic cells (or any other type of cell) prevent or stop stalled ribosomes?

Every time I search for “eukaryotic rescuing stalled ribosomes”, I am constantly only  presented with references to tmRNA in E. Coli.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5311927/

Comment: Googling works fine with a slight amount of persistence: the 6th result for _stalled eukaryotic ribosomes_ is [this overview paper](http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royptb/372/1716/20160183.full.pdf).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRNA_surveillance